how to make a data.frame from truncated information and regex in R/Python?
I have a data.frame in R with one column and truncated lines that I would like to divide into three columns via regex, for example:
dados <- c(
  "N 2022NE001264 75",
  "FRETES INTERNACIONAIS LTDA                                 7.500,00 C",
  "N 2022NE000286 84",
  "UNIRIO UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO ESTADO RJ                         2.856,71 C",
  "N 2022NE001297 48                                                   720,00 C",
  "N 2022NE001333 16",
  "CASTRO COMERCIO LTDA                       5.256,00 C",
  "N 2022NE001353 92",
  "CONSTRUCOES E INSTALACOES LTDA                           734,20 C",
  "N 2022NE000279 12",
  "UNIRIO UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO ESTADO RJ                            180,00 C",
  "N 2022NE000293 12",
  "EQUIPAMENTOS E PRODUTOS PARA LABORATORIOS L               1.716,00 C"
)

dados_df <- data.frame(V1 = dados)

with regex, I would like to transform my data.frame into something like this
nota                     org                                     value 
N 2022NE001264 75   FRETES INTERNACIONAIS LTDA                  1500.00 C
N 2022NE000286 84   UNIRIO UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO ESTADO RJ    2856.71 C
N 2022NE000297 48                                                720.00 C
N 2022NE001333 16   CASTRO COMERCIO LTDA                        5256.00 C
N 2022NE001353 92   CONSTRUCOES E INSTALACOES LTDA               734.00 C
N 2022NE000279 12   UNIRIO UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO ESTADO RJ     180.00 C
N 2022NE000293 12   EQUIPAMENTOS E PRODUTOS PARA LABORATORIOS L 1716.00 C

This is the code I have developed so far:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

dados_df <- dados_df %>%
  mutate(
    nota = str_extract(V1, "^N\\s\\d+NE\\d+\\s\\d+\\s*"),
    org = str_extract(V1, "(?<=\\d\\s{1,}).*(?=\\s{2,}\\d)"),
    value = str_extract(V1, "\\d+\\.?\\d*,\\d{2}\\sC$")
  )


Where does the value 1500.00 C come from on the first row of the result?

Base R:
text <- gsub("(N \\d{4})", "\n\\1", paste(dados_df$V1, collapse = " "))
read.table(text = gsub("(?<=\\d \\d{2}) | {4,}", "|", text, perl = TRUE), 
           sep = "|",  strip.white = TRUE, col.names = c("nota", "org", "value"))

               nota                                         org      value
1 N 2022NE001264 75                  FRETES INTERNACIONAIS LTDA 7.500,00 C
2 N 2022NE000286 84    UNIRIO UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO ESTADO RJ 2.856,71 C
3 N 2022NE001297 48                                               720,00 C
4 N 2022NE001333 16                        CASTRO COMERCIO LTDA 5.256,00 C
5 N 2022NE001353 92              CONSTRUCOES E INSTALACOES LTDA   734,20 C
6 N 2022NE000279 12    UNIRIO UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO ESTADO RJ   180,00 C
7 N 2022NE000293 12 EQUIPAMENTOS E PRODUTOS PARA LABORATORIOS L 1.716,00 C


text <- gsub("(N \\d{4})", "\n\\1", paste(dados_df$V1, collapse = " "))
a <- gregexec("(?m)(?<nota>^N \\w+ \\d+) (?<org>\\D*?)\\s++(?<value>\\d.+?C)", text, perl = TRUE)
data.frame(t(regmatches(text, a)[[1]][-1,]))

               nota                                         org      value
1 N 2022NE001264 75                  FRETES INTERNACIONAIS LTDA 7.500,00 C
2 N 2022NE000286 84    UNIRIO UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO ESTADO RJ 2.856,71 C
3 N 2022NE001297 48                                               720,00 C
4 N 2022NE001333 16                        CASTRO COMERCIO LTDA 5.256,00 C
5 N 2022NE001353 92              CONSTRUCOES E INSTALACOES LTDA   734,20 C
6 N 2022NE000279 12    UNIRIO UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO ESTADO RJ   180,00 C
7 N 2022NE000293 12 EQUIPAMENTOS E PRODUTOS PARA LABORATORIOS L 1.716,00 C


dados_df %>%
   separate_longer_delim(V1, delim = regex("( {4})+")) %>%
   mutate(name = case_when(
            str_detect(V1, "N \\d{4}")~"nota",
            str_detect(V1, "\\d.*C")~"value",
            TRUE~"org"),
          row_id = cumsum(name == "nota")) %>%
   pivot_wider(values_from = V1, values_fn = str_squish)

# A tibble: 7 × 4
  row_id nota              org                                         value     
   <int> <chr>             <chr>                                       <chr>     
1      1 N 2022NE001264 75 FRETES INTERNACIONAIS LTDA                  7.500,00 C
2      2 N 2022NE000286 84 UNIRIO UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO ESTADO RJ    2.856,71 C
3      3 N 2022NE001297 48 NA                                          720,00 C  
4      4 N 2022NE001333 16 CASTRO COMERCIO LTDA                        5.256,00 C
5      5 N 2022NE001353 92 CONSTRUCOES E INSTALACOES LTDA              734,20 C  
6      6 N 2022NE000279 12 UNIRIO UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO ESTADO RJ    180,00 C  
7      7 N 2022NE000293 12 EQUIPAMENTOS E PRODUTOS PARA LABORATORIOS L 1.716,00 C

